# Not getting output in Selenium for chrome browser -- Attached output image - It Should connect google page

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I tried the following program to learn Selenium but the output doesn't open in Chrome Browser. It should open Google in Chrome.

My Chrome browser version is 63.0.3239.108 (Official Build) (64-bit)
My Selenium Version 3.8.1

Here is what I see:

[image: output]

And here is the code:

```
   package co.selenium.webdrivers.basic;
   import java.util.Collections;
   import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

   public class firstseleniumproject {

    WebDriver driver;

   public void invokebrowser()
  {
    try {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Sainathan\\Desktop\\studies\\Selenium\\Chrome Driver\\chromedriver.exe");

        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        options.addArguments("start-maximized");
        options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", 
        Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https//www.google.co.in");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    firstseleniumproject obj1 = new firstseleniumproject();
    obj1.invokebrowser();
} }
```

Answer (score 0):

> driver.get("https//www.google.co.in");

^^ you are directing the browser to navigate to an invalid URL.  fix the missing colon it so it contains: "https://" rather than "https//"